# How can I add data types for fields in Draw.io's Database 3 Software diagram type's table representations?

Tags: uml, erd, draw.io

Using Draw.io's MacOS Desktop release,'Database 3' is a Software diagram option:
[image]

A table representation in it looks like this:

[image]

My question is, how can I add a data type to a field in a column, and not just tag it to the name? It doesn't appear to be possible, at first, on the right side-menu, nor on the initial double-click on the representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon the initial double click on the representation, single left-clicking to the right of the second column brings up the Table menu. The second button Insert Column Right allows for this:
[image]

Upon inserting it, clicking the right-arrow key positions the cursor for entry of the type:
[image]